# Puppet - CSV file header

Tags: csv, puppet

I'm, writing a Puppet (3.6.2) module that reads data fields from a CSV file via the extlookup function and I cannot figure out how to tell extlookup that the first line is the header field. Does extlookup support this? If not, can anyone recommend an external function I could import and use?

thanks,

PS - Yes I know about hiera, and having the data in YAML or JSON files but my requirement is CSV files only.

Brandon

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `extlookup()` is pretty well [documented](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.stable/function.html#extlookup).  It makes no special provision for column headers, which are by no means an inherent feature of CSV format.  Indeed, if your header line is not readable as a data line, then your file is not CSV at all.

Supposing that your file is indeed valid CSV, the absolute simplest solution would be to ignore the issue.  It presents a problem only if the first column heading duplicates an actual or potential data name.  If it does not, then you will never look up or use the psuedo-value represented by the first row.

If your file in fact is not CSV on account of its first line, or if the first column name conflicts with a real data name, then it seems the next best alternative would be to just remove that line, or to avoid creating it in the first place.  I don't see any reason why one of these should not be possible.

> I know about heira, and having the data in YAML or JSON files but my requirement is CSV files only.

How sad.  Do be aware that `extlookup()` has long been deprecated, and it was removed from Puppet 4.

I'm inclined to suggest you implement a translator from CSV to Hiera-friendly YAML, and use Hiera in your module.  Alternatively, Hiera supports custom backends, and it's not too hard to write one.  I am unaware of an existing CSV backend for Hiera, but you could write one.  Ignoring a header line would then be under your control, and you would simultaneously achieve a measure of future-proofing.